# How to scroll layout which have 3 list view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one layout. This layout contain 3 list view with the height of wrap_content data in the Listview are not fix. When Listview have a liitel huge data at that time the data goes to underneath and the data can not able to see,so i want to scroll the view with all three Listview how it is possible.

Any one have an idea about this ?

This is my view which contain 3 Listview, now it's with the less data but when the data will make huge at that time the last Listview have a problem to view. I want to scroll the grey colored view...

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use linear layout instead of listview in your xml file.
This is your xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scr" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/r2" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingTop="100dip"
        android:paddingBottom="100dip">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/l1" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="#00B2EE">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/l2" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="#00EE76">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/l3" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="#7171C6">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and put another xml which will be inflated by list.

this is your main activity class.

```
package com.list.add;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewlistActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    LinearLayout l1,l2,l3;
    ScrollView scrollView;
    ViewGroup contentView;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l1);
        l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l2);
        l3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l3);
        scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scr);
        contentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.r2);
        scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new ScrollPager(scrollView, contentView));
        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, contentView.getPaddingTop());
            }
        });
        list.add("Parth");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Parth");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Shah");
        list.add("Parth");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Parth");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Chirag");
        list.add("Shah");

        list1.add("Parth");
        list1.add("Parth");
        list1.add("Parth");
        list1.add("Parth");
        list1.add("Parth");
        list1.add("Parth");

        list2.add("Kalpesh");
        list2.add("Kalpesh");
        list2.add("Kalpesh");
        list2.add("Kalpesh");
        list2.add("Kalpesh");
        list2.add("Kalpesh");
        list2.add("Kalpesh");
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(list2);
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) 
        {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(list.get(i));
        l1.addView(vi);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++) 
        {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(list1.get(i));
        l2.addView(vi);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<list2.size(); i++) 
        {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(list2.get(i));
        l3.addView(vi);
        }
    }

}
```

and make one scroller class like this:

```
public class ScrollPager implements OnTouchListener
public ScrollPager(ScrollView aScrollView, ViewGroup aContentView)
    {
        mScrollView = aScrollView;
        mContentView = aContentView;
        scroller = new Scroller(mScrollView.getContext(), new OvershootInterpolator());
        task = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                scroller.computeScrollOffset();
                mScrollView.scrollTo(0, scroller.getCurrY());

                if (!scroller.isFinished())
                {
                    mScrollView.post(this);
                }
            }
        };
    }
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        // Stop scrolling calculation.
        scroller.forceFinished(true);
        // Stop scrolling animation.
        mScrollView.removeCallbacks(task);

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
```

Comment: This works for me. I understand it may not be most memory efficient as  we will have to do that explicitly etc but in my case I am not using more than 5 items so I am good. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use weight attribute `android:layout_weight="1"` in each ListView in XML layout. So that it will divide the screen  with equal space for each listview and your scrolling will work for each ListView.

Comment: hello sujit but I use the Relative layout in that the android:layout_weight property is not support.

Comment: why are you using RelativeLayout ? Any specific reason ? You should use LinearLayout because you have 3 listView vertically aligned ???

Comment: but design of the application matter with the this view so i need this design in the relative layout..

Answer (score 1):

If you are presenting stuff in a vertical or horizontal stack, you should be using `LinearLayout` and then use the `layout_weight` attribute to control the proportions of the individual rows/columns within the container.

If you want screen-sized, set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `fill_parent` otherwise you will not get all available screen dimension.  If you try to use `wrap_content` for height, everything will collapse, unless you resort to additional layout constraints, e.g. `minHeight`.

We use this everywhere and it is quite reliable.  For three items, you can use `1/1/1` or `3/3/3`.

The weights also do not have to be equal!  You can divide up the proportions any way you wish; the weights are just relative ratios of the entire span (width/height).  E.g. if you want the middle element twice the size, use `1/2/1`; if you want it 40% use `30/40/30` or `3/4/3`.

A good "trick" is to use `layout_weight`=1 on exactly one row/column (others default to zero), and it will "fill-in" any remaining space.  This is a common layout scenario.

If you need the stack to be scrollable, you can put it into a `ScrollView`.  In this case, you must set the `layout_height` of the `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content`, and you will be subject collapsing depending on the whim of the layout system (meaning you need to then use min/max constraints).

Answer (score 1):

Instead, let me give my best idea for the same kind of implementation.

Have you ever thought to use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) for the same kind of implementation? Just show the 1st group item as expanded and make other 2 groups as collapsed, just expand it when user click on the particular group.

Here are some examples for the same:

1. http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html
2. http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/

I am sure this idea is not good but if you implement this then you will sure found beneficial in your case.