# Not scrollable listview in scroll view android

Tags: android, listview, scroll

i need to make a layout that is scrollable, holds a listview that is not scrollable(full height of the content). So when i scroll the content above the listview is showed, and the full listview is displayed. 
Is this possible in android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657961/how-to-scroll-layout-which-have-3-list-view

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by ListView ( not scrollable).. will it have predefined items(count) ?

you can have a `<ScrollView></ScrollView>` inside of which a normal(linear/relative layout say id `insidelayout1`)

For single item of your ListView, create a separate xml(say item.xml) and try to inflate `item.xml` into `insideLayout1`.

Will that work for you.. or detail out your requirement...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put list view inside the scroll view than you have to fix the height of list view.
otherwise you can't scroll it properly.